# List Comprehension - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I tried to convert the following into a list comprehension, but it's giving me an invalid syntax error. I tried a few solutions such as zipping the combinations, but I can't get it to work.

I'm obviously missing some fundamental understanding of what I can and cannot do with list comprehensions. What is my mistake?

**Works**

```
def myfun(x, y, z):
        for c in (x,y,z), (x,z,y), (y,x,z), (y,z,x), (z,x,y), (z,y,x):
            print(c)
```

**Does not work**

```
def myfun(x, y, z):
    [print(c) for c in (x,y,z), (x,z,y), (y,x,z), (y,z,x), (z,x,y), (z,y,x)]
```

Comment: What is the output that you are looking for?

Comment: Same output as the one that works; I would just rather do as a list comprehension than a for loop.

Comment: A list comprehension is not just a one-line replacement for an arbitrary `for` loop. A list comprehension *always* creates a new list, whether you save a reference to it or not. Your `for` loop does *not* create a new list; it just iterates over a list.

Answer (score 6):

You have two issues here.

Firstly, you need to wrap all your elements into a list:

```
[print(c) for c in [(x,y,z), (x,z,y), (y,x,z), (y,z,x), (z,x,y), (z,y,x)]]
```

Secondly, `print` is a statement in Python 2, not a function, so it can't be used in a list comprehension as these can only contain expressions.

You can do `from __future__ import print_function` to change it into a function, as it is in Python 3.

However, this isn't really appropriate in a list comprehension. They are for calling something on every element and returning the result as a list; you shouldn't use them for their side effects.

Comment: Good catch on the print. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: `print` is a built-in function in python 2.7, so part of this answer is not actually true. docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#built-in-functions

Comment: You don't have to wrap the elements in a list in Python 2; iterating over a tuple works just fine: `[x for x in 1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: @chepner I don't understand your point. As the OP demonstrates, the existing version was a syntax error; you need to wrap those separate tuples in something, whether it's another tuple or a list.

Comment: They got *a* syntax error, likely related to using the `print` statement instead of the `print` function.

Answer (score 3):

Doing this as a list comprehension is sort of odd since you are creating a list filled with the return value of `print` which is `None`.  If you really want to do it this way:

```
def myfun(x, y, z):
    [print(c) for c in [(x,y,z), (x,z,y), (y,x,z), (y,z,x), (z,x,y), (z,y,x)]]
```

then you need to make the things that you are trying to iterate over an iterable (wrap the (x, y, z), ... in a list)

Also consider using itertools.permutations instead to simplify your code:

```
import itertools
def myfun(x, y, z):
    [print(x) for x in itertools.permutations([x, y, z])]
```

I really should stress that it is odd to do this as a list comprehension and you should do this as a for loop to avoid unnecessarily creating that list...

```
import itertools
def myfun(x, y, z):
    for x in itertools.permutations([x, y, z]):
        print(x)
```

Comment: Python 2 allows you to iterate over a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

## That's not the point of list comprehensions...

A list comprehension is intended/useful to **create a new list** of objects, without having to explicitly use a traditional *for* loop.

From Python documentation on [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

> List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists. Common applications are to **make new lists** where each element is the result of some operations applied to each member of another sequence or iterable, or to **create a subsequence** of those elements that satisfy a certain condition.

What you're trying, instead, is more like a one-liner to print stuff on screen. You don't really need/care about getting a list out of the list comprehension. BTW: you would only get a list of `None` objects in this case, because that's what the `print` function returns. It is not useful *and* a waste of memory/CPU.

In your case, I would prefer a normal *for* loop: it would be more readable and explicit (which is always a good thing!).

**A couple of notes**

If you still *really* want to use a list comprehension for printing in python 2.7, you will have to first do: `from __future__ import print_function`. That's necessary because inside a list comprehension you need to use the *print function*, not the old *print statement*.

The rest of the list comprehension is ok: you can iterate over a tuple of tuples. That's what `(x,y,z), (x,z,y), (y,x,z), (y,z,x), (z,x,y), (z,y,x)` is, even without the external parenthesis (which in this form are implicit), because a tuple is an iterable (no need to make a list out of it, as others have suggested).

Also, to be fair: @chepner is right in every comment he made so far.